# How to change sound using distance sensor

Tags: audio, arduino, raspberry-pi, distance

I'm trying a project to simulate a brass trombone. The materials I'm using are a Seeed Studio Ultrasonic distance sensor, Raspberry Pi, and an Arduino. I'm going to connect the sensor to the Arduino, and the Arduino to the Raspberry Pi.

I'm looking to have the Raspberry Pi play one steady sound out of the audio jack. As the distance between my hand and the sensor get larger, the pitch of the emitted sound should get lower.

I'm not too familiar with using audio in programming, or too much of programming for that fact. Could someone help me write up some code (preferably in java or C#)? I'm very anxious to do this as I play trombone in school. Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As not to recreate the brass trombone from scratch, use a Midi Synth on the Pi, such as TiMidity (apt-get install timidity) or alike. With this you can bridge between the Arduino's output and the note(s) sent to TiMidity to play out the Pi's speaker.

Comment: Would I use the arduino serial to send messages to TiMidity? If so, do I use a program such as this? [link](http://www.spikenzielabs.com/SpikenzieLabs/Serial_MIDI.html)   @mpflaga

Comment: That is the idea. Where as I see http://www.varal.org/ttymidi/ may be better and do the job of both SM + TiMidity